# PHP - If something is the case, do nothing

Tags: php, logic

Is this a proper way to say: if something is the case, do nothing?

```
if ( ($hostNameInfo == $hostNameInput) && ($hostAddressInfo == $hostAddressInput) )
{
  return;
}
```

**Update:**
I'm not inside a function. :(
So the return is just nonsense.

Here is more code:

```
//if the input fields are equal to database values, no need to update and waste resources,hence, do nothing:
if ( ($hostNameInfo == $hostNameInput) && ($hostAddressInfo == $hostAddressInput) )
{
  //do nothing
}
//If, however, (they are NOT equal and) input fields are not empty:
elseif (!empty($hostNameInput) && (!empty($hostAddressInput)))
{
 //do something.
}
```

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: You're not exactly doing nothing there: You are returning from a function. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Pekka: no. :( I have no functions here. I cannot use break; or exit();... I will edit my question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you should do the opposite, do something if your condition is not verified

```
if($hostNameInfo != $hostNameInput || $hostAddressInfo != $hostAddressInput) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: +1 Having code "do nothing" is not nice practice and should be avoided.

Comment: IMHO it's cleaner to check preconditions at the beginning of the function and return if there isn't need to do anything. And you save one indentation level! :)

Comment: @phadej : I personnaly find it cleaner to have only one `return` in a function and not use it as a void return. And in the case it is a precodition, why not checking before calling the function ?

Comment: @Serty: Sorry, I've edited my code, it's not just a if condition is a if else. Still, does your answer still applies? I mean, the best way do deal with this "do nothing" is to, actually ignore it? Am I getting this?

Comment: @Serty: It depends. I mean by preconditions the checks as in the question. They may be so complicated or just that long,
that it's easier to break them apart than trying to add up them into one conditional. Also you may argue to follow jensgram solution, but it's not always cheap to calculate all of them, sometimes even impossible, as if later checks are not sensible if earlier are already failed.

Comment: @MEM : "the best way do deal with this "do nothing" is to, actually ignore it?", indeed.  
@phadej : I think all of this is pretty subjective (like all coding conventions), in case of many checks with no else, I would use only one if (with some indentations in the if condition to make it readable), everyone has his own habits and likes :)

Comment: @Pekka Why? Maybe "doing nothing" makes the code more human-readable (after all, all code must be maintained by humans), and if the logic is correct, then PHP shouldn't care. No? I know it's not _usual_, and could almost surely be refactored to avoid doing nothing, but I don't see why doing nothing is "not nice practice and should be avoided". Maybe the do-nothing block has a nice juicy comment in there.

Answer (score 20):

For do nothing you simply can type:

```
function relax() {
    ;
}

if (($hostNameInfo == $hostNameInput) && ($hostAddressInfo == $hostAddressInput)) {
    relax();
}
```

Comment: Up-voted this because it actually answered the question.

Comment: curious about this... is this mentioned in the PHP Manual?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not mentioned in the PHP manual. This is an old characteristic of C.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I assume you're inside a function in which case it does what you expect, although multiple `return` statements within a function *can* lead to confusion and a lack of readability.</del> (Apparently I was wrong.)

Instead, I prefer to let all conditional blocks (my description for the code between in the `if`'s `{...}` block) contain the relevant code, i.e., write the conditional check in such a way that the total condition evaluates to `true` when additional processing (sub-flow) is needed:

```
if ($hostNameInfo != $hostNameInput || $hostAddressInfo != $hostAddressInput) {
    // do stuff, else skip
}
```

Furthermore, you can extract the conditional statement in order to improve *both* readability and simplicity of control flow:

```
$hostInfoEqualsInput = ($hostNameInfo == $hostNameInput && $hostAddressInfo == $hostAddressInput);
if (!$hostInfoEqualsInput) {
    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE** (based on updated question). Consider this instead:

```
$fieldsAreFilled = (!empty($hostNameInput) && !empty($hostAddressInput));
$hostInfoEqualsInput = ($hostNameInfo == $hostNameInput && $hostAddressInfo == $hostAddressInput);

if ($fieldsAreFilled && !$hostInfoEqualsInput) {
    ...
}
```

---

**ERGO**
Minimize branch rate and avoid empty blocks by writing conditions you *want* to be met, not all the exceptions you want to ignore (subjective).

Comment: Ohh... so we can not only store values on variables but, we can store, as well, states or conditions? I didn't know about that.

So, and according to Serty Oan answer and Pekka comments, we should know that if we arrive on a situation where we have to comment like //do nothing that probably means that we are NOT properly structuring our code hm?

Comment: I will consider Serty Oan answer but I will mark yours as relevant. Thanks a lot for your time, I will ask my comment question on another question. It's a self question by itself. :)

Thanks a lot again,
MEM

Comment: @MEM Well, the stored "condition" (e.g., `$fieldsAreFilled`) is really just a Boolean value of the expression on the right-hand side. No magic here.

Comment: Well... but I'm having troubles to understand the conditional later on: if(true and !true) do something? What does that mean?... Reply if you feel like, of course.. kind of lost.

Comment: @MEM Basically it is just this written more self-explanatory: `if ((!empty($hostNameInput) && !empty($hostAddressInput)) && !($hostNameInfo == $hostNameInput && $hostAddressInfo == $hostAddressInput)) { ...`

Comment: I was missing the context of the true and false. Clear now. ;) Thanks.

Comment: BTW You might find this interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement#Criticism

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about best practices here..
One of best practice things is that routine shall have [single exit point](http://www.tomdalling.com/coding-tips/coding-tip-have-a-single-exit-point), though it is [widely](http://ivan.truemesh.com/archives/000611.html) [discussed](http://secretgeek.net/monkey_exit.asp) and is up to developer/style.

UPDATE:

New answer, since the question was changed:

Don't see any reason to add additional checks if the code should run only under some circustances. To make the code more readable, you should stuck to whatever you accept as easy-maintainable, like this (or something similar):

```
// Do something only if required
if (($hostNameInfo != $hostNameInput) || ($hostAddressInfo != $hostAddressInput)) &&
    !empty($hostNameInput) && !empty($hostAddressInput))
{
    echo 'place some code here';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that single exit point. I didn't know about it. It's related to functions, but my question misslead to that direction. Thanks for your time on updating your question. I will mark your question as relevant. Regards.

Comment: these `empty()` calls are doing too much work.  The variables are already assumed to be declared, so you only need a truthy check `&& $hostNameInput && $hostAddressInput`.

Answer (score 0):

A native do_nothing() function would be very nice and readable sometimes.

To avoid stressing alerts from syntax checkers & linters, that go crazy when you have an empty `if` block, I use:

```
echo(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

The other possibility is to throw a new exception, which you can later catch in your application.

**UPDATE:** not inside the function this is probably a bad idea.